# Excel vlookup to copy multiple columns of values from one table to another

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need to merge sales data with inventory data, to produce a useful re-order sheet.

My Sales per Quarter table looks like this:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Title</td><td>Q1</td><td>Q2</td><td>Q3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item0</td><td>22</td><td>33</td><td>44</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item1</td><td>12</td><td>31</td><td>14</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2</td><td>32</td><td>1</td><td>13</td></tr>
</table>
```

My Inventory Pivot Table like this:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Title</td><td>Sku</td><td>Stock Qty</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2</td><td>ZZ1</td><td>35</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item0</td><td>XX1</td><td>37</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>XX2</td><td>31</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item1</td><td>YY1</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

The goal is to add columns for each Quarter to the Inventory table, then pull data into the array of columns by looking up the Title. Thus the header row would look like this:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Title</td><td>Sku</td><td>Stock Qty</td><td>Q1</td><td>Q2</td><td>Q3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I found a function along these lines... VLookup(Title,TableRange,{2,3,4},false) and used SHIFT+CONTROL+ENTER to make it an array, which adds the braces around the whole function. But it fails.

Using Excel for Mac, 2016.

Comment: You should look into PowerPivot. By adding your data to a data model you can join your datasets together. Another option would be to use Access instead of Excel. Your Access database could export to Excel as needed.

Comment: @MichaelZ. - Good idea, but PowerPivot is not available in Excel for Mac, and I don't have Access, or any real experience with databases. Might have to invest in PC :(